# How to fix ValueError for piecewise function plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math

I am currently working on the following python script to plot the given piecewise function over the specified domain `np.linspace(1.0, 3.0)` and have run into some plotting errors. When I run the script, I am given the following error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (42,)`. I have tried adjusting the length of `domain` to match that of `codomain` by `domain = np.linspace(1.0, 3.0, 42)` but have had no luck. Here is my code given below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def f(x):

    image = []
    for p in x:
        if p in np.linspace(1.0, 1.5):
            y = 1.000004 * (p - 1.0) + 0.486068 * (p - 1.0) ** 2 - 0.106566 * (p - 1.0) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in np.linspace(1.5, 2.0):
            y = 0.608198 + 1.406152 * (p - 1.5) + 0.326219 * (p - 1.5) ** 2 - 0.052277 * (p - 1.5) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in np.linspace(2.0, 2.5):
            y = 1.386294 + 1.693164 * (p - 2.0) + 0.247803 * (p - 2.0) ** 2 - 0.032798 * (p - 2.0) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in np.linspace(2.5, 3.0):
            y = 2.290727 + 1.916372 * (p - 2.5) + 0.198606 * (p - 2.5) ** 2 - 0.021819 * (p - 2.5) ** 3
            image.append(y)

    return image


domain = np.linspace(1.0, 3.0)
codomain = f(domain)

plt.plot(domain, codomain)
plt.show()
```

Disclaimer: this is my first post on this site so if there is anything I need to adjust for better feedback please let me know.

Comment: You need to debug your code.  Add `else: print(p)` to the end of your for loop to see which values are being dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what `np.linspace` is doing.  Specifically, the values in `np.linspace(1,1.5)` are not guaranteed to be in `np.linspace(1,3)`

I would suggest reading the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to understand why this is.

You seem to want to split the original input into quartiles, which you could do with `np.arraysplit(x,4)`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(x):

    image = []
    a,b,c,d = np.array_split(x,4)
    for p in x:
        if p in a:
            y = 1.000004 * (p - 1.0) + 0.486068 * (p - 1.0) ** 2 - 0.106566 * (p - 1.0) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in b:
            y = 0.608198 + 1.406152 * (p - 1.5) + 0.326219 * (p - 1.5) ** 2 - 0.052277 * (p - 1.5) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in c:
            y = 1.386294 + 1.693164 * (p - 2.0) + 0.247803 * (p - 2.0) ** 2 - 0.032798 * (p - 2.0) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        elif p in d:
            y = 2.290727 + 1.916372 * (p - 2.5) + 0.198606 * (p - 2.5) ** 2 - 0.021819 * (p - 2.5) ** 3
            image.append(y)
        else:print(p)
    return image


domain = np.linspace(1.0, 3.0)
codomain = f(domain)

plt.plot(domain, codomain)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, Chris! Before reading your answer I did something similar: I changed the structure of my 'if' statements to, for example, (in the first one) 'if 1.0 <= p <= 1.5:'. However, I will still read the documentation you provided.